# assign stdout to file

Tags: macos, terminal

I consider myself an advanced beginner. Know enough to shoot myself. But so far I can't find a way to have the output of terminal to a file. In other words change stdout and stderr to a file name.I'd execute this before a script and reset defaults after. I'm not asking how to redirect.

Comment: It looks like you're asking how to redirect. Or has MacOS another name for it?

Comment: in more or less every shell I ever worked with, the `>` operator will write the output of a command to a file. ex: `ls -al . >  ./list-of-all-files.txt`. is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Also.. what @FrankThomas shows.. he isn't redirecting STDERR, only STDOUT.  Each out has a number, stdout is #1, stderr is #2.. `command >out 2>&1` is one of many ways to make sure the stderr is in your stream.  You can also specify another file for that purpose. `2>&1` means redirect sdterr to the same place stdout is going to.  If you need help isolating stderr from stdout, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

stdout is a device file. You can't change it's name, at least, not without fiddling around with the operating system.

Device files are special, they're sort of like a mirror: one program sends bytes to it, and if another program just so happens to be observing the bytes, they will reflect into that program (with the exception of things like /dev/null and /dev/zero)*. This is done live. For a simple terminal program that logs an output on the screen, it sends everything to stdout, and the terminal emulator (or TTY) is the program that is observing stdout.

Redirection is pretty much the only way you can accomplish the behavior of "renaming stdout". stdout doesn't mean "print to terminal", it's just a device that spits out the data sent to it. The terminal is what's reading stdout.

By using redirection, you are telling the terminal: "Instead of printing stdout, push the reflected data somewhere else." In this case, you can send it to a file of your choice.

The same is true for stderr. It's basically stdout but for more important alerts, but both function exactly the same. You can specify which one of the two you want to redirect, allowing you to log data for both device files.

To send stdout and stderr to separate files:

`echo -n "foobar" 1> output.log 2> error.log`

*This is an oversimplification. Your disks also interface through device files, and you can read and write raw bytes on the disk.